# 90's (+/- a decade) book where an undersea vessel discovers a hidden race at the bottom of the Mariana Trench

Tags: story-identification, books

The following is what I can remember, or think I remember, from the book:

- A DSV goes down into an ocean trench (possibly the Mariana). They
  enter a lava vent/tube.
- They discover this "race" of people that are leary of outsiders.
- They find out that this people has done away with sexual intercourse and, I think, carries on with cloning.
- One of the members of the group is a bit aggressive, but kisses one of the woman of the people. He becomes angered when one of thr men of people kisses    him in ignorance. He accidentally kills the man.
- The people force out the strangers.
- At the end, I think the woman character remembers being on land and looking in the sky where she sees a UFO cloak itself. Determined to expose the secret people she seeks out others on land and finds out she has been returned to a past time in order that no one will believe her story.

Those are the details I think I remember. There are emotions and images associated with the "scenes" that I remember, but am unsure how to properly express them, if even necessary. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could almost be a match to some parts of Peter Watts' Rifters series (Starfish, Maelstrom, Behemoth: B-Max and Behemoth: Seppuku).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good albeit not complete match for Robin Cook's novel [*Abduction* (2000)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?25867).

> A DSV goes down into an ocean trench (possibly the Mariana). They enter a lava vent/tube.

The submersible *Oceanus* is exploring a seamount which is part of or close to the Mid-Atlantic ridge, but is sucked down a deep shaft.  One of the characters, Suzanne, says that it "could have been some kind of magma pipe".

> They discover this "race" of people that are leary of outsiders.

The three people in the submersible, Suzanne, Perry and Donald, together with divers Michael and Richard, eventually arrive in the undersea land of Interterra, which is in the Mohorovicic discontinuity.  It's inhabited by "first-generation humans" who moved down there around 550 million years ago.

> They find out that this people has done away with sexual intercourse and, I think, carries on with cloning.

The Interterrans live for a few hundred years; when they die, their bodies are disposed of  and their minds are uploaded into a computer.  New bodies are manufactured from tissue cultures and after a while they download themselves into them.  They have sex, but it's not related to reproduction.

> One of the members of the group is a bit aggressive, but kisses one of the woman of the people. He becomes angered when one of thr men of people kisses him in ignorance. He accidentally kills the man.

At a party, Richard kisses some women, although "kissing was not part of the Interterrans’ normal salutational repertoire".  Later, the Interterran man Sart strokes Richard's back and touches his head above his ear.  Richard gets angry because he "can’t stand queers" and hits Sart; Sart's head hits the corner of a marble nightstand and he dies.

> The people force out the strangers.

> At the end, I think the woman character remembers being on land and looking in the sky where she sees a UFO cloak itself. Determined to expose the secret people she seeks out others on land and finds out she has been returned to a past time in order that no one will believe her story.

Perry, Donald, Michael and Richard, together with some others, try to escape in the submersible, but the Interterrans intercept them and send them back in time to 1791.